# How do I create a bifurcation diagram for the below iterative map?

Tags: plotting, map, difference-equations

I have tried to create a bifurcation diagram for the following iterative map: x[n+1]=-r Log x[n], x[1]=0.711 and  r=1/log(n(n+1)) using the following code But it doesn't work. Any help?

```
res = Flatten[Table[
  list = RecurrenceTable[{x[n+1] == -r (Log[x[n]]), x[1] == 0.5}, x, {n, 1, 100}];
  Replace[DeleteDuplicates[Take[list, -100]], x_ -> {r, x}, 1]
 , {r, 0.005,0.3, 0.01}], 1]
ListPlot[res]
```

Comment: replace `0.3.0` with `0.3`?

Comment: yes , thanks , it is a wrong typo

Comment: I didn't see the `r=1/log(n(n+1))` part before.  That would make the system non-autonomous so I don't think there's a normal kind of attractor to plot.  Also, in the first time step, `Log[n(n+1)]==0`, so `r` would be dividing by zero.  Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code basically works.  Right now, you plot the first 100 time steps.  I'd suggest increasing the initial number of time steps taken to get past transient behavior.

```
res = Flatten[
  Table[list = 
    RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == -r (Log[x[n]]), x[1] == 0.5}, x, {n, 1, 400}];
    Replace[DeleteDuplicates[Take[list, -100]], x_ -> {r, x}, 1]
  , {r, 0.005, 0.3, 0.01}], 1];

ListPlot[res, PlotRange -> {All, All}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not very exciting though!